# Visual Studio 2019 completely freezes when going down to data flow level

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, freeze

I've checked "Skip validation when opening a package" so when opening a package it doesn't freeze, but when going down to data flow level, it starts validating the connection and freezes. I would chalk it up to it being a big database, but on other machines, it works without a hitch. Do you guys have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

I too was having this issue when going into a data flow. I am on VS 2019 16.11 and SSIS 3.16 (not Preview 4.0). I changed the DelayValidation to True on the Data Flow and the project, and it resolved my issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your individual connections, you might need to set delay validation to true on the connections too.

[image: Update Connections]

Comment: I tried to set it to true, but it froze at Testing Connectivity :/ (for reference, I tried this yesterday also, left vs running for 2 hours to check if it would continue, but no luck sadly)

Comment: Please update your question with screenshots, testing connectivity wont be called if validation is set to delayed on the connection, unless you are manually clicking the Test Connectivity button?

Answer (score 0):

I Updated My Visual Studio 2019 to latest version and Problem Solved!